# FBWebDialog rotation issue in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

When I use following code to open FBWebDialog, Once FBWebDialog is open click in username textfield and keyboard is displayed now if you rotate iPad device, FBWebDialog is not auto-rotating to landscape orientation.

```
[FBSession setActiveSession: [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission] ];
[[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    switch (status) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            [self getMyData];
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
            NSString *errorCode = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode];
            NSString *errorReason = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedReason];
            BOOL userDidCancel = !errorCode && (!errorReason || [errorReason isEqualToString:FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue]);
            if(error.code == 2 && ![errorReason isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginCancelled"]) {
                UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kFBAlertTitle message:kFBAuthenticationErrorMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:kOk otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [errorMessage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                errorMessage = nil;
            }

        }
        break;
    // presently extension, log-out and invalidation are being implemented in the Facebook class
    default:
        break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
    }
}];
```

Following are steps to reproduce this issue :

1. Open FBWebialog which opens inside iPad app
2. Click in username textfield and keyboard is displayed
3. Now if you rotate iPad device, FBWebDialog is not auto-rotating to landscape orientation.

Please help me to solve this issue....

Comment: Please format your code properly by indenting 4 spaces

Comment: Anyone can help me on this. I also posted this bug on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=created,but still not getting any kind of reply at all.

Comment: Any body please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its bug from facebook side, here is the my query posted to the facbook support team. Even not getting any kind of response from Facebook,its ridicules...

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/355080977928726?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52820409e9c884976463112

Comment: And Facebook still have not resolved this issue 3 years later, in iOS SDK 3.5.2. Absolute madness. It just looks awful on the iPad, when a landscape dialog is presented and its contents are displayed in portrait on its side. This company is worth over $100 billion, and they cannot even address a simple issue like this. What hope do we have?