# FBWebDialog going upside down

Tags: ios, facebook, orientation, facebook-ios-sdk

My app supports only `landscape` mode as I am presenting `FBwebDialog` It goes upside down.

[image]

As you see in the screensort The device is in the Landscape mode but the Facebook dialog is going upside down and always goes this way.

Not sure whose bug is this. What I can do to make it go landscape.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19926788/1702413

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Facebook SDK Version 3.20

Comment: has anyone fixed this issue yet?